# From design point of view, what are the purpose of these vertical lines on iMac G3?

Tags: line-art

[image]

Why they add these vertical lines on the machine? I don't think it is just for fun, it must be have some meaning to add this. I don't think a designer will ignore the details, and also it is in the keyboard too.

Answer (score 4):

Why can't aesthetics be enough of an answer? There isn't any physical depth there. It's all smooth plastic. The lines are merely for visual interest. Pinstripe patterns have always lent a traditional aire of elegance to many things. They serve to break up a wide field of color - if the plastic were merely white, there's no interest. If it were merely grey it would appear drab. The variation creates elegance and a sense of motion or interest while at the same time not appearing too bright or too dark.

If anything the vertical lines would help the screen *seem* larger by counter-acting the ever-present horizontal lines which would appear on the screen itself (text, menus, etc.).

Now.. don't ask about the round mouse..... that was a stumble in usability :)

Comment: but is it the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just as on a woman's dress, vertical lines will make her look thinner, here they make the computer look a little sleeker.

Answer (score 0):

My guesses:

-to show there is more to it...so ton of untouchable thin lines always remind more inside.

-As scott said make screen to be bigger by being part of something bigger.

-Highrises?

Answer (score 0):

The iMac G3 was the first model of the iMac line of personal computers made by Apple. So we are talking about the first personal mac, and unlike the first PCs (integrated circuits, metal, thick plastic, I'm not really sure to be honest) it was made with beautiful brightly colored, translucent plastic.

I'd therefore agree with Scott: The reason is aesthetics. Something familiar for Apple, well known for bringing nice materials and carefully designed shapes (and software) to the table.